# Undefined reference with multiple files in C++

Tags: c++, class, oop, undefined

I created this small program using multiple files, I removed most of the class members for simplicity

Program Description:

- Class **User** has a **service** member object
- **Service** class contains one member function to perform string splitting
- Class **User** uses the **stringSplitter** member function from **Service** class
- **main()** is empty, I just wanted to test the program

I have the following error (when I try to build and run):

**undefined reference to `Service::stringSplitter**

How can I solve it?

**Here is my code:**

User.h

```
#ifndef USER_H_INCLUDED
#define USER_H_INCLUDED
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include "Service.h"
using namespace std;

    class User
    {
    public:
        User ();
        User (const string &);
        Service getService ();
    
    private:
    
        Service generalService;
    
    };
    
    
    #endif // USER_H_INCLUDED
```

User.cpp

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include "User.h"
using namespace std;

User :: User (const string &str)
{
    vector <string> pieces = getService().stringSplitter (str, ',');

}
Service User :: getService ()
{
    return generalService;
}
```

Service.h

```
#ifndef SERVICE_H
#define SERVICE_H
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

class Service
{
public:
    vector <string> stringSplitter (string s, char delimiter);

};

#endif // SERVICE_H
```

Service.cpp

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include "Service.h"
using namespace std;

vector <string> stringSplitter (string s, char delimiter)
{
    vector <string> vec;
    string x;
    for (int i = 0; i < (int) s.length(); i++)
    {
        x += s[i];
        if (s[i] == delimiter)
        {
            x.erase (x.length() - 1, 1);
            vec.push_back (x);
            x.clear();
       }
    }
    return vec;
}
```

Comment: Needs to be `Service::stringSplitter` in Service.cpp

Comment: Woe, woe and thrice woe.  Do not use `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`, especially with `using namespace std`, and even more so in a header file.  It is non-portable and puts the entire standard library into the global namespace, which can only lead to trouble somewhere down the line.  Instead, #include just the headers you need, no more and no less, and qualify names in the standard library with `std::` in your code.